# Hotlink Protection from .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

I have tried using .htaccess file for hotlink protection. But I don't seem to get it to work. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```css
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?templatesumo\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?google\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?(.*\.)?google\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?bing\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?(.*\.)?bing\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?yahoo\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?(.*\.)?yahoo\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?ask\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?(.*\.)?ask\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?pinterest\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?(.*\.)?pinterest\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?facebook\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?(.*\.)?facebook\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?twitter\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?(.*\.)?twitter\.(.+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ https://i.imgur.com/VjYukxC.png [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I suggest to add an ability to detect https:// as well.

Comment: Well, we cannot magically guess what is wrong with your setup, except that such approach is not a robust solution. You will have to start debugging: first find out if that dynamic configuration file is parsed and applied _at all_ for example by placing a definit syntax error in there and monitoring your http servers error log file. That log file is the major place to consult anyway if something is not working as expected in an apache environment. If the file is parsed, then you need to check if the rewriting module is loaded and activated.

Comment: I have tried with https as well. It just allows my own site to show images. But the problem that I am facing is that, other sites are still able to hotlink to my website. How can I stop it.